# Is gravity really indistinguishably from centripetal acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, centripetal-force

I know that gravity and linear acceleration are indistinguishable. I.e., if I am put in a closed box I would not be able to tell the difference between the box staying on earth and the box travelling through empty space accelerated at $1 g$. I also know that theoretically one can [simulate gravity in a space station by means of rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wheel_space_station). But are gravity and centripetal acceleration also really indistinguishably? My question arises from my intuition: if my closed box (with me inside) rotates fast enough about some axle, I will get dizzy; however, I don't think gravity could give me dizziness.

Another setting: if I jump inside of my box, while it is still on Earth, I will hit the floor. If the box is linearly accelerating in space, the same will happen. But if the box is rotating about some axle and I jump, I will hit the walls (assuming it's just me and the box, no air whatsoever).

Comment: Remember if the box is spinning the "walls" are the "floor". The only difference will be on scale - if the box is small enough you will measure a difference in force between your head and feet - in a big enough rotating space station you wouldn't notice

Comment: *"if I am put in a closed box I would not be able to tell the difference between the box staying on earth and the box travelling through empty space accelerated at 1g"* - this isn't quite correct as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_general_relativity#Tidal_effects)

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent when your box is small enough to neglect tidal effects and the changes in direction due to gravity pointing radially.

Remember, these are inertial frames - if you jump in the box, you have some inertia tangential to the circle you were travelling in, and since these are small distance scales, you won't notice that the box is actually angling upwards a bit (mathematically, this is because $\sin\theta \approx \theta$ for small $\theta$). Thus, it'll seem like you and the box are travelling in the same direction (or rather, not travelling at all since you don't know you're moving when you're in the box), and centripetal force will push you back down to the "floor".

Comment: Great! And what about the dizziness? I know it's not a physical concept, but it still intrigues me.  If they are really indistinguishable I have to accept that one of the following statements is true: i) That, for some reason, I won't get dizzy no matter how fast the box spins. ii) That gravity can make me dizzy in the same way as rotating does.